# Got the following error while building a gradle project

Tags: node.js, npm, build.gradle, npm-install, ivy

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':nodeSetup'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
  >   Could not find org.nodejs:win-x64/node:8.13.0.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >
  > - https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.13.0/ivy.xml
  >     Required by:
  >      project :

Comment: did you solve this issue. I've the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue but it is asking for a node.exe file. I solved the missing ivy.xml file using this code in the build.gradle:

```
repositories.whenObjectAdded {
    if (it instanceof IvyArtifactRepository) {
        metadataSources {
            artifact()
        }
    }
}
```